# How do you write a clearcase script that iterates through a list of selected SPRs and determines if there is a conflict?

Tags: clearcase

Everytime we do a build we select a certain list of "Resolved" SPRs to be included.  Too often one (or some) of these SPRs was merged on top of an SPR that was *not* part of the original selected list of "Resolved" SPRs.  Thus, we have to go through a manual process of looking at the offending SPR and see what other source code is associated with it.

I would like to automate this process and I was wondering if anybody knows how to write a script that returns a list of offending SPRs and associated files given a selected list of "Resolved" SPRs that are to be included in the next build.

Comment: SPR = "Software Problem Report", I presume? Ie. the name of a Defect in your ClearQuest project, linked to your ClearCase project?

Comment: Correct. They are basically bug reports.

Answer (score 0):

If you are comparing labelled entities you can run "cleartool diff" to show what files changed between baselines.  Then, iterate over the result set from "diff" and grab the SPR link or attribute from each element.  Add the SPR to a set of SPRs if it does not already exist in the set.  Sort your list and Bob's your uncle.

Perl is your friend here.  How are your SPRs linked to file and directory elements?  Let me know and I may be able to provide more guidance.